# Oracle Enterprise Manager 12c Installation error on Oracle Enterprise Linux 6

Tags: oracle12c, weblogic12c, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-enterprise-manager, oracle-enterprise-linux

I have Oracle Enterprise Linux 6 Update 5 installed as an OS, and installed Oracle Database 12c. Using SQL Developer, I am able to confirm that the Database is working fine. I have even had success connecting to the database from another computer in the institution using SQL Developer and my local address (172.16.5.40). I tried to install Oracle Enterprise Manager 12c, and run into the following error:

```
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:About to execute plug-in Start Oracle Management Service
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:The plug-in Start Oracle Management Service is running
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Internal PlugIn Class: oracle.sysman.oms.StartOMS
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Classpath = /u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/sysman/jlib/omsConfig.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/sysman/jlib/emcore_client.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/../modules/com.bea.core.apache.log4j_1.2.13.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/jlib/rcucommon.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/sysman/jlib/emagentSDK.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/../oracle_common/modules/oracle.xdk_11.1.0/xmlparserv2.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/../oracle_common/modules/oracle.odl_11.1.1/ojdl.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/../oracle_common/modules/oracle.xdk_11.1.0/xml.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/../oracle_common/modules/oracle.jdbc_11.1.1/ojdbc6dms.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/../oracle_common/modules/oracle.dms_11.1.1/dms.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/../oracle_common/modules/oracle.odl_11.1.1/ojdl.jar:/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/jlib/rcu.jar
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:BaseConfiguration:invoke:Starting BaseConfiguration  invoke method on an aggregate=oracle.sysman.top.oms for Action=configuration in step=12:microstep=0
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Fetching the ports from staticports.ini file: /u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/.gcinstall_temp/staticports.ini
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Starting OMS ...
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Executing command: /u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/bin/emctl start oms
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c Release 3  
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Copyright (c) 1996, 2013 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Starting Oracle Management Server...
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Starting WebTier...
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:WebTier Could Not Be Started
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Error Occurred: WebTier Could Not Be Started
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Please check /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/log/emctl.log for error details
SEVERE: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Starting of OMS failed.
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Starting export oms config...
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Executing command: /u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/bin/emctl exportconfig oms -keep_host -dir /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/backup
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c Release 3  
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Copyright (c) 1996, 2013 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password : Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password : ExportConfig started...
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Machine is Admin Server host. Performing Admin Server backup...
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Exporting emoms properties...
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Exporting secure properties...
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Export has determined that the OMS is not fronted 
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:by an SLB. You have chosen to export the local 
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:hostname. The exported data may ONLY be imported 
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:on a host with the same hostname. Please see the 
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:EM Advanced Configuration Guide for more details.
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Exporting configuration for pluggable modules...
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Preparing archive file...
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Backup has been written to file: /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/backup/opf_ADMIN_20140128_134121.bka
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:The export file contains sensitive data. 
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms: You must keep it secure.
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:ExportConfig completed successfully!
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:Export config of OMS is successful.
INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:The plug-in Start Oracle Management Service has failed its perform method
```

emctl.log:

```
2014-01-28 17:05:01,727 [main] INFO  wls.OMSController main.219 - Executing emctl command : start
2014-01-28 17:05:16,102 [main] INFO  util.EmctlUtil logp.251 - Output messages of the command :
opmnctl stopall: stopping opmn and all managed processes...

2014-01-28 17:05:16,102 [main] INFO  util.EmctlUtil logp.251 - error messages of the command :

2014-01-28 17:07:18,004 [main] INFO  util.EmctlUtil logp.251 - Output messages of the command :
opmnctl startall: starting opmn and all managed processes...

2014-01-28 17:07:18,005 [main] INFO  util.EmctlUtil logp.251 - error messages of the command :
================================================================================
opmn id=OracleServer.Compsci:6701
Response: 0 of 1 processes started.

ias-instance id=instance1
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ias-component/process-type/process-set:
  ohs1/OHS/OHS/

Error
--> Process (index=1,uid=163667581,pid=5583)
  time out while waiting for a managed process to start
  Log:
  /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/WebTierIH1/diagnostics/logs/OHS/ohs1/console~OHS~1.log


2014-01-28 17:07:18,005 [main] ERROR commands.BaseCommand logAndPrint.620 - WebTier Could Not Be Started
2014-01-28 17:07:18,006 [main] ERROR wls.OMSController main.252 - OMSController failed for start oms
2014-01-28 17:07:18,008 [main] ERROR wls.OMSController main.253 - OMSController Error: WebTier Could Not Be Started
    java.lang.Exception: WebTier Could Not Be Started
    at oracle.sysman.emctl.commands.StartCommand.startOMS(StartCommand.java:257)
    at oracle.sysman.emctl.commands.StartCommand.execute(StartCommand.java:155)
    at oracle.sysman.emctl.wls.OMSController.main(OMSController.java:233)
2014-01-28 17:07:19,187 [main] DEBUG ctxt.CommandContext trace.419 - Starting processing of arguments
2014-01-28 17:07:19,190 [main] DEBUG ctxt.CommandContext trace.419 - Option keep_host entered
2014-01-28 17:07:19,190 [main] DEBUG ctxt.CommandContext trace.419 - Value of option dir specified as /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/backup
2014-01-28 17:07:19,191 [main] DEBUG ctxt.CommandContext trace.419 - Done processing options passed on command line
2014-01-28 17:07:19,191 [main] DEBUG ctxt.CommandContext trace.419 - Checking if mandatory params are passed.
2014-01-28 17:07:19,191 [main] DEBUG ctxt.CommandContext trace.419 - Reading value of password option sysman_pwd
2014-01-28 17:07:19,230 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - ExportConfig started...
2014-01-28 17:07:19,230 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - oracle home is /u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms
2014-01-28 17:07:19,231 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - instance home is /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1
2014-01-28 17:07:19,231 [main] DEBUG ctxt.CommandContext trace.419 - Validating CommandContext and setting default values
2014-01-28 17:07:19,232 [main] DEBUG ctxt.CommandContext trace.419 - Setting optional parameter oms_only to default value false
2014-01-28 17:07:19,238 [main] INFO  oms.AdminCredsWalletUtil setInstanceHome.177 - Getting credentials from wallet
2014-01-28 17:07:19,685 [main] INFO  oms.AdminCredsWalletUtil setInstanceHome.192 - Read the credentials from wallet
2014-01-28 17:07:19,685 [main] INFO  util.EmctlUtil logp.251 - Connecting over t3s to: OracleServer.Compsci/7102 using id: weblogic
2014-01-28 17:07:22,059 [main] INFO  mas.CredStoreUtil logp.251 - getCredential : Got creds for mapName -EM keyName - REPOS_DETAILS
2014-01-28 17:07:23,134 [main] INFO  mas.CredStoreUtil logp.251 - getCredential : Got creds for mapName -EM keyName - ENCR_DETAILS
2014-01-28 17:07:23,839 [main] INFO  oms.HAUtil verifyReposPwd.95 - Sysman password is valid
2014-01-28 17:07:23,840 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - sysman password validated
2014-01-28 17:07:23,841 [main] INFO  oms.AdminCredsWalletUtil setInstanceHome.177 - Getting credentials from wallet
2014-01-28 17:07:23,886 [main] INFO  oms.AdminCredsWalletUtil setInstanceHome.192 - Read the credentials from wallet
2014-01-28 17:07:23,886 [main] INFO  util.EmctlUtil logp.251 - Connecting over t3s to: OracleServer.Compsci/7102 using id: weblogic
2014-01-28 17:07:23,915 [main] INFO  mas.CredStoreUtil logp.251 - getCredential : Got creds for mapName -EM keyName - REPOS_DETAILS
2014-01-28 17:07:23,969 [main] INFO  mas.CredStoreUtil logp.251 - getCredential : Got creds for mapName -EM keyName - ENCR_DETAILS
2014-01-28 17:07:24,689 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Admin backup is true
2014-01-28 17:07:26,395 [main] INFO  script.ScriptExecutor output.2119 - read domain from "/u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/user_projects/domains/GCDomain"
2014-01-28 17:07:31,898 [main] INFO  script.ScriptExecutor output.2119 - succeed: read domain from "/u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/user_projects/domains/GCDomain"
2014-01-28 17:07:32,136 [main] INFO  script.ScriptExecutor output.2119 - find Server "EMGC_ADMINSERVER" as obj0
2014-01-28 17:07:32,231 [main] INFO  script.ScriptExecutor output.2119 - succeed: find Server "EMGC_ADMINSERVER" as obj0
2014-01-28 17:07:32,323 [main] INFO  script.ScriptExecutor output.2119 - find Server "EMGC_OMS1" as obj1
2014-01-28 17:07:32,325 [main] INFO  script.ScriptExecutor output.2119 - succeed: find Server "EMGC_OMS1" as obj1
2014-01-28 17:07:32,338 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - admin backup cmd is /u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/bin/zip -q -r -9 /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/backup/GCDomain_backup.zip user_projects -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_ADMINSERVER/tmp* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_ADMINSERVER/logs* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_ADMINSERVER/adr* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_ADMINSERVER/*.log* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_ADMINSERVER/*.trc* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_ADMINSERVER/*.lck* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_OMS1/tmp* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_OMS1/logs* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_OMS1/adr* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_OMS1/*.log* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_OMS1/*.trc* -x user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/EMGC_OMS1/*.lck*
2014-01-28 17:07:37,168 [main] INFO  oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - zip exited with code 0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,168 [main] INFO  oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - whether admin pack failed: false
2014-01-28 17:07:37,169 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - admin server backup completed successfully
2014-01-28 17:07:37,169 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Export readme file is /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/backup/plugins.list
2014-01-28 17:07:37,260 [main] DEBUG deploymentservice.EMPluginDeploymentUtil logp.251 - Version obtained from configmanager 12.1.0.3.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,261 [main] DEBUG deploymentservice.EMPluginDeploymentUtil logp.251 - Unique OMS key obtained/generated = GCDomain#EMGC_OMS1#12.1.0.3.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,275 [main] DEBUG deploymentservice.EMPluginDeploymentUtil logp.251 - Returning OMS GUID: 69258938A596AB98276D063F08AD4BE0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,282 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.971 - Fetching plugins for OMS 69258938A596AB98276D063F08AD4BE0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,408 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.emas:12.1.0.5.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,409 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.mos:12.1.0.5.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,410 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.satc:12.1.0.2.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,410 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.db:12.1.0.5.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,410 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.xa:12.1.0.5.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,410 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.secl:12.1.0.2.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,410 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.secs:12.1.0.2.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,411 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.sesy:12.1.0.2.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,411 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.soee:12.1.0.2.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,411 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.sidb:12.1.0.2.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,412 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.smdn:12.1.0.2.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,412 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.emct:12.1.0.5.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,412 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.sehc:12.1.0.4.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,412 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.smf:12.1.0.3.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,412 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.sovn:12.1.0.2.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,413 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.vt:12.1.0.5.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,413 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.emfa:12.1.0.5.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,413 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.empa:12.1.0.4.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,413 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.smad:12.1.0.1.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,413 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.smbs:12.1.0.1.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,415 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.smis:12.1.0.2.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,415 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.smss:12.1.0.3.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,416 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.soav:12.1.0.4.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,416 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.savf:12.1.0.1.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,416 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.bda:12.1.0.3.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,416 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.sysman.ssa:12.1.0.7.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,416 [main] DEBUG inventory.EMPluginInventoryManager getAllPluginsDeployed.990 - Obtained plugin for this oms: oracle.em.ssad:12.1.0.2.0
2014-01-28 17:07:37,418 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Backup is being written to file: /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/backup/export.properties
2014-01-28 17:07:37,421 [main] INFO  oms.AdminCredsWalletUtil setInstanceHome.177 - Getting credentials from wallet
2014-01-28 17:07:37,443 [main] INFO  oms.AdminCredsWalletUtil setInstanceHome.192 - Read the credentials from wallet
2014-01-28 17:07:37,444 [main] INFO  util.EmctlUtil logp.251 - Connecting over t3s to: OracleServer.Compsci/7102 using id: weblogic
2014-01-28 17:07:37,476 [main] INFO  mas.CredStoreUtil logp.251 - getCredential : Got creds for mapName -EM keyName - REPOS_DETAILS
2014-01-28 17:07:37,614 [main] INFO  mas.CredStoreUtil logp.251 - getCredential : Got creds for mapName -EM keyName - ENCR_DETAILS
2014-01-28 17:07:37,972 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Retrieving java callbacks from em_gcha_callbacks table
2014-01-28 17:07:37,988 [main] INFO  oms.HAUtil addJarsInClassLoader.464 - Added jar /u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/sysman/jlib/emCORE.jar to classpath
2014-01-28 17:07:38,018 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - executing java callback: oracle.sysman.core.ocm.gcha.OCMHACallbacks
2014-01-28 17:07:38,021 [main] INFO  oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Got export data from callback module ocm
2014-01-28 17:07:38,021 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - preparing archive file
2014-01-28 17:07:38,022 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Adding: /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/backup/GCDomain_backup.zip
2014-01-28 17:07:38,622 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Adding: /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/backup/plugins.list
2014-01-28 17:07:38,623 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Adding: /u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/oms/sysman/prov/agentpush/agentpush.properties
2014-01-28 17:07:38,632 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Adding: /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/backup/export.properties
2014-01-28 17:07:38,633 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Adding: 
2014-01-28 17:07:38,633 [main] ERROR oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - Error reading file: . Skip file for archive.
2014-01-28 17:07:38,651 [main] INFO  oms.AdminCredsWalletUtil setInstanceHome.177 - Getting credentials from wallet
2014-01-28 17:07:38,675 [main] INFO  oms.AdminCredsWalletUtil setInstanceHome.192 - Read the credentials from wallet
2014-01-28 17:07:38,676 [main] INFO  util.EmctlUtil logp.251 - Connecting over t3s to: OracleServer.Compsci/7102 using id: weblogic
2014-01-28 17:07:38,708 [main] INFO  mas.CredStoreUtil logp.251 - getCredential : Got creds for mapName -EM keyName - REPOS_DETAILS
2014-01-28 17:07:38,772 [main] INFO  mas.CredStoreUtil logp.251 - getCredential : Got creds for mapName -EM keyName - ENCR_DETAILS
2014-01-28 17:07:38,958 [main] DEBUG oms.ExportConfigOMSCmds logp.251 - ExportConfig succeeded!
```

console~OHS~1.log:

```
--------
14/01/28 17:05:18 Start process
--------
/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/Oracle_WT/ohs/bin/apachectl startssl: execing httpd
[Tue Jan 28 17:05:18 2014] [warn] Errors will be logged into /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/WebTierIH1/diagnostics/logs/OHS/ohs1/ohs1.log
[Tue Jan 28 17:05:19 2014] [warn] Errors will be logged into /u01/app/oracle/em/gc_inst/WebTierIH1/diagnostics/logs/OHS/ohs1/ohs1.log
Audit init
Unable to resolve address for localhost:6700
ONS runtime exiting

--------
14/01/28 17:07:18 Stop process
--------
/u01/app/oracle/em/middleware/Oracle_WT/ohs/bin/apachectl stop: httpd stopped
```

ohs1.log:

```
[2014-01-28T17:05:20.2995-05:00] [OHS] [NOTIFICATION:16] [OHS-9999] [mod_weblogic.c] [host_id: OracleServer.Compsci] [host_addr: 127.0.0.1] [pid: 5583] [tid: 139855446157120] [user: oracle] [VirtualHost: main]  WebLogic Server Plugin version 1.1 <WLSPLUGINS_11.1.1.6.0_LINUX.X64_111122.1115.0001>

[2014-01-28T17:05:20.5147-05:00] [OHS] [NOTIFICATION:16] [OHS-9999] [core.c] [host_id: OracleServer.Compsci] [host_addr: 127.0.0.1] [pid: 5583] [tid: 139855446157120] [user: oracle] [VirtualHost: main]  Oracle-Application-Server-11g/11.1.1.6.0 Oracle-HTTP-Server (Unix) mod_ssl/11.0.0.0.0 OtherSSL/0.0.0 mod_plsql/11.1.1.0.0 mod_onsint/2.0 configured -- resuming normal operations

[2014-01-28T17:07:19.3932-05:00] [OHS] [NOTIFICATION:16] [OHS-9999] [core.c] [host_id: OracleServer.Compsci] [host_addr: 127.0.0.1] [pid: 5583] [tid: 139855446157120] [user: oracle] [VirtualHost: main]  caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

my hosts file contains 3 entries:

```
127.0.0.1   OracleServer.Compsci OracleServer
172.16.5.40 OralceServer.Compsci OracleServer
::1         OracleServer.Compsci OracleServer
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have altered your hosts file to look someting like this :

```
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
11.111.1.111    srv01.com           srv01
```

And you can ping the `srv01` and that `11.111.1.111` will respond.

Make sure that the `6700` port is not in use by any process.

Comment: Thanks @Up_One. I've tried that with no luck but it's all good. It was for school (final project) but I ended up simply not installing  it.

Comment: open door for me and i will do it for you @ :)

Answer (score 0):

there are some tips for installing Oracle OEM.
These tips has been achieved after 3 weeks struggling with installing of OEM:

```
     please install Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package from 
     https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999
     Visual C++ 2012,2015 update3,2021
     alter system set "_allow_insert_with_update_check"=true scope=both;
     alter system set session_cached_cursors=500 scope=spfile;
     shut immediate
     startup
     alter profile default limit password_verify_function null;
     Alter pluggable database all open;
```

be sure all ports of OEM is open on your windows